# Solution basis of underdetermined equation set in python

Tags: python, linear-equation

I have an underdetermined equation set (m equations of n variables, m smaller than n). As such, if it is solvable then the set of solutions are a linear space (if it is a homogenic set) or affine space (non-homogenic).

Is there an easy way in Python (possibly with other libraries) to obtain this space - for example, a basis of which?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the previous poster said, you'll want linalg from SciPy, but focus on the [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) solution.  The matrix U is the basis for the output vectors.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting. Trying `scipy.linalg.svd` for a few simple underdetermined inputs, the U matrix doesn't look anything like a basis for the solution set. Also, I don't see what you'd do for an inhomogeneous system.

Comment: It's actually the QR decomposition that's relevant here, not SVD.

Answer (score 3):

Use [linalg](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.html) package from [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org)

Comment: My bad, I've pasted wrong link. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.html

Comment: scipy.linalg.orth ? Or better yet, ask this question on the SciPy list.

Comment: Scroll down under "decompositions" and look at "svd"

Comment: Sorry, look for svd on this link: http://wiki.aims.ac.za/mediawiki/index.php/Python:scipy_module:linalg#Decompositions.